# date insert inserts only 1900-01-01

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

i have bulk insertion to my table so i use XML in stored procedure. below is my stored procedure, the problem is with the date column 'DateOfBirth' in which it sets it as 1900-01-01 and not taking the date i insert in the ASP page

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PolicyBulkInsert]
 @XMLData xml
AS
 Create table #tempPolicy(
  ClientID bigint null,
  FirstName varchar(50) null,
  MiddleName varchar(50) null,
  LastName varchar(50) null,
  [Address] varchar(50) null,
  Telephone varchar(50) null,
  Email varchar(50) null,
  LivingPlace varchar(50) null,
  PassportNo varchar(50) null,
  Gender varchar(50) null,
  Dateofbirth date null,
  PolicyPlan varchar(50) null,
  Destination varchar(50) null); 


 Insert into PolicyDetails(ClientID, FirstName,MiddleName, LastName, [Address], Telephone, Email, LivingPlace, PassportNo, Gender, Dateofbirth, PolicyPlan, Destination, PolicyNumber)

  Select
  PolicyDetail.query('ClientID').value('.', 'bigint') as ClientID,  
  PolicyDetail.query('FirstName').value('.', 'varchar(50)') as FirstName,
  PolicyDetail.query('MiddleName').value('.', 'varchar(50)') as MiddleName,
  PolicyDetail.query('LastName').value('.', 'varchar(50)') as LastName,
  PolicyDetail.query('Address').value('.', 'varchar(50)') as [Address],
  PolicyDetail.query('Telephone').value('.', 'varchar(50)') as Telephone,
  PolicyDetail.query('Email').value('.', 'varchar(50)') as Email,
  PolicyDetail.query('LivingPlace').value('.', 'varchar(50)') as LivingPlace,
  PolicyDetail.query('PassportNo').value('.', 'varchar(50)') as PassportNo,
  PolicyDetail.query('Gender').value('.', 'varchar(50)') as Gender,
  PolicyDetail.query('DateOfBirth').value('.', 'Date') as DateOfBirth,
  PolicyDetail.query('PolicyPlan').value('.', 'varchar(50)') as PolicyPlan,
  PolicyDetail.query('Destination').value('.', 'varchar(50)') as Destination,
  ( select  (isnull(max(PolicyNumber),0)+1) from PolicyDetails) as PolicyNumber

 FROM
  @XMLData.nodes('/PolicyDetails/PolicyDetail')AS xmlData(PolicyDetail)

RETURN
```

the code behind in vb.net which will save the records in the GridView to the table

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Dim txtClientID As Label = CType(Repeater1.FindControl("txtClientID"), Label)
        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        sb.AppendLine("<?xml version=""1.0"" ?>")
        sb.AppendLine("     <PolicyDetails>")
        Dim txtFirstName As TextBox
        Dim txtMiddleName As TextBox
        Dim txtLastName As TextBox
        Dim txtPassportNo As TextBox
        Dim ComboGender As DropDownList
        Dim txtBirthdate As TextBox
        Dim theCultureInfo As IFormatProvider = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", True)
        Dim StartDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStartF.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", theCultureInfo)
        Dim EndDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEndF.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", theCultureInfo)


        For Each row As GridViewRow In gvContacts.Rows
            txtFirstName = CType(row.FindControl("txtFirstName"), TextBox)
            txtMiddleName = CType(row.FindControl("txtMiddleName"), TextBox)
            txtLastName = CType(row.FindControl("txtLastName"), TextBox)
            txtPassportNo = CType(row.FindControl("txtPassportNo"), TextBox)
            txtBirthdate = CType(row.FindControl("txtBirthdate"), TextBox)
            ComboGender = CType(row.FindControl("ComboGender"), DropDownList)
            txtClientID = CType(txtClientID, Label)

            If txtFirstName Is Nothing OrElse txtMiddleName Is Nothing OrElse txtLastName Is Nothing Then
                Return
            End If

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text.Trim()) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMiddleName.Text.Trim()) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLastName.Text.Trim()) Then
                lblMsg.Text = "All fields are required!"
                Return
            Else
                sb.AppendLine("     <PolicyDetail>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <ClientID>" & txtClientID.Text.Trim() & "</ClientID>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <FirstName>" & txtFirstName.Text.Trim() & "</FirstName>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <MiddleName>" & txtMiddleName.Text.Trim() & "</MiddleName>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <LastName>" & txtLastName.Text.Trim() & "</LastName>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <Address>" & txtCity.Text.Trim() & "</Address>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <Telephone>" & txtPhone.Text.Trim() & "</Telephone>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <Email>" & txtEmail.Text.Trim() & "</Email>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <LivingPlace>" & ComboLivingPlace.SelectedItem.Text & "</LivingPlace>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <PassportNo>" & txtPassportNo.Text.Trim() & "</PassportNo>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <Gender>" & ComboGender.SelectedItem.Text & "</Gender>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <Dateofbirth>" & txtBirthdate.Text.Trim() & "</Dateofbirth>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <PolicyPlan>" & ComboPlan.SelectedItem.Text() & "</PolicyPlan>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <Destination>" & ComboCountry.SelectedItem.Text() & "</Destination>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <EffectiveDate>" & StartDate & "</EffectiveDate>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <ExpiryDate>" & EndDate & "</ExpiryDate>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <PolicyDuration>" & ((EndDate.Date - StartDate.Date).TotalDays).ToString().Trim() & "</PolicyDuration>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <Premium>" & txtLastName.Text.Trim() & "</Premium>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <TotalPremium>" & txtLastName.Text.Trim() & "</TotalPremium>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <IssuedDate>" & Date.Today.Date.AddHours(4) & "</IssuedDate>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <CreatedDate>" & Date.Today.Date.AddHours(4) & "</CreatedDate>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <Status>Active</Status>")
                sb.AppendLine("         <CreatedBy>" & txtClientID.Text.Trim() & "</CreatedBy>")
                sb.AppendLine("     </PolicyDetail>")
            End If
        Next

        sb.AppendLine("     </PolicyDetails>")

        Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString)
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("PolicyBulkInsert", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@XMLData", sb.ToString())

            If con.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                con.Open()
            End If

            Dim affRow As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            If affRow > 0 Then
                lblMsg.Text = "Successfully " & affRow & " record inserted."
                'PopulateData()
                AddRowsToGrid()
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: Without a copy of `@XMLData` we can only guess, but sounds like your node has a value of `''` for the date, which is implicitly cast to `1900-01-01`.

Comment: On a different note `(SELECT (ISNULL(MAX(PolicyNumber), 0) + 1) FROM PolicyDetails) AS PolicyNumber` is a bad idea. You could have race conditions meaning that the same value is assigned twice, and rows that are deleted will be reused; which is unlikely to be wanted (especially if that's your primary key). What you're after there is the `IDENTITY` property or a `SEQUENCE`.

Comment: Dear Larnu... i know but this is not new database an idiot designed it as this and the PolicyNumber is not PrimaryKey the set it as SEQUENCE in the database.

Comment: If it was a [`SEQUENCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), then you wouldn't be using that subquery, @Ahmed . I'm not saying that you designed the database but I am saying that you want to change that design, or highlight the problems there upwards.

Comment: i already did the new design for the new year beginning all will be transferred. but any help with the date ??

Comment: I've already commented on that, @Ahmed. I can't help you any further right now, as we still don't have that XML.

Comment: XML coding in the code behind

Comment: That isn't XML, that's application code.

Comment: solved... XML is case sensitive and i wrote it DateOfBirth in code and Dateofbirth in XML

Comment: You should consider deleting this question. Since it is just typo it is not going to help anybody in the future.